# how do I output the filtered todo list in React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

It is console logging the right array out all the time, but the point here is that it should be outputting that in the 'TodoList.tsx'. Not sure how to get that fixed in this case. Anyone who could help me with this. To see the bigger picture, please click on this link:

[Link to codesandbox todo](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu/todo-react-typescript)

I want the returned value from **App.js** currentFilter function pass it to **TodoListItem.js**, so it will update the map function constantly when user clicks on filter buttons.

```js
// TodoFilter

import React from 'react';

interface TodoListFilter {
    currentFilter: CurrentFilter;
}

export const TodoFilter: React.FC<TodoListFilter> = ({ currentFilter }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            Filter
            <li onClick={() => currentFilter('All')}>All</li>
            <li onClick={() => currentFilter('Complete')}>Completed</li>
            <li onClick={() => currentFilter('Incomplete')}>Incompleted</li>
        </ul>
    )
}

// App.js

  const currentFilter: CurrentFilter = filterTodo => {
    let activeFilter = filterTodo;
    switch (activeFilter) {
      case 'All':
        return todos;
      case 'Complete':
        return todos.filter(t => t.complete);
      case 'Incomplete':
        return todos.filter(t => !t.complete);
       default:
        console.log('Default');
    }
  }
  
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TodoList 
        todos={todos} 
        toggleTodo={toggleTodo} 
        deleteTodo={deleteTodo} 
        editTodo={editTodo} 
        saveEditedTodo={saveEditedTodo} 
        getEditText={getEditText}
      />
      <TodoFilter currentFilter={currentFilter}/>
      <AddTodoForm addTodo={addTodo}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
  
// TodoListItem

  import React from 'react';
import { TodoListItem } from "./TodoListItems"; 

interface TodoListProps {
    todos: Array<Todo>;
    toggleTodo: ToggleTodo;
    deleteTodo: DeleteTodo;
    editTodo: EditTodo;
    getEditText: GetEditText;
    saveEditedTodo: SaveEditedTodo;
    currentFilter: CurrentFilter;
}

export const TodoList: React.FC<TodoListProps> = ({ todos, toggleTodo, deleteTodo, editTodo, getEditText, saveEditedTodo, currentFilter }) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {todos.map((todo, i) => {
                return <TodoListItem key={i} 
                            todo={todo} 
                            toggleTodo={toggleTodo} 
                            deleteTodo={deleteTodo} 
                            editTodo={editTodo} 
                            saveEditedTodo={saveEditedTodo} 
                            getEditText={getEditText}
                        />
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}

//Folder structure
src
-App.tsx
-AddTodoForm.tsx
-TodoFilter.tsx
-TodoList.tsx
```

Comment: current filter seems to be called but never updates state.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the list not updating is that `currentFilter` passed as a prop to `TodoList` component is not used there at all.

Please consider two ways of solving it:

- Pass a full list + filter object and apply filter inside `TodoList`
- Apply filter object on the list at `App` component level and pass filtered list to `TodoList` component.

Personally I would go with the second approach but it's up to you :)

Comment: could you give a short example of that of the second approach

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two arrays.One is original and second is filtered like this in your example.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(initialTodos);
const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(initialTodos);
```

Now you need to send filtered array in list component.Any updation or deletion you have to make on your `todos` array.And in currentFilter,you have to filter from original array that is `todos` and set it to filtered array in like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setFiltered(todos);
}, [todos]);
```

Link of forked sandbox : [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hermann-uguku)

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Not really, maybe you could fork the codesandbox and try to implement your solution in there.